# Controlling a light in an electrical circuit separately from others in a daisy chain set up. Possible?

Tags: switch, light

Is there a way to manage a light in an electrical circuit, the one wired directly to the switch, independent of others wired to the rest of the circuit a daisy chain configuration?

I am not able to run new wiring to power the remaining lights in the circuit unless I tap from the first light (the one that I want to control separately.

EDITS to original posting:
Basically, a floodlight was wired to a basic electric switch with 3 wires (hot, neutral, ground). Later on I added soffit LED lights to the area where the floodlight is but given I did not have a power source nearby, I just tapped into the wires of the floodlight and connected all the LED lights with pigtails into the same circuit.

Now I want to turn the floodlight on/off independent of turning the soffit lights on/off. Is this possible? If so how?

There is no conduit between the switch and floodlight. The electrical cable travels behind a brick wall quite a distance.

Thanks for any help!

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a bypass

Comment: Usually a switch will control all the devices wired to it. What are the other devices (lights? outlets? fans? etc?) that are on this circuit? How do you want them to be controlled (always powered or switched)? What kind of wiring do you have in the wall (actually conduit - that'll make your life easy!, cables with 2 or 3 conductors)? With some more details like that, and maybe even pictures of the wiring behind the switch and behind this first light, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the boxes in question please?

Comment: You could try a wireless light switchs.

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you don't think about where you're tapping. There isn't really an easy way to solve this, short of smart bulbs.

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking of keeping the floodlight as is which operates dusk to dawn and as suggested, adding a wireless light switch for the soffit lights so the two operate independently. Replies appreciated.